# iterating a coxph() model using various sets of covariates

Tags: r

I'm still a little new to R, so this may be a basic question.

I am looking for risk estimates for a joint-cox model using coxph().  I have to iterate the model for about 60 times using various combinations of variables.  Since each iteration of the model will have different covariates (and main exposures), I want to write one function to do it.  In the age-adjusted model I just had the main exposure, everything runs fine.  I can add the covariates, it runs... I just need a way to write a single function where the "covars" can be whatever I put into the function call.

*Note: this is a simplified version, it runs just fine, I just want to make it work without writing out 60 unique iterations of it.*

```
   subtype <- function(expo, covars){


    temp <- coxph(Surv(FAIL, OUTCOME) ~ joint[[expo]]*strata(EVENT2)+
                  covars+
                  cluster(ID)+strata(AGE_INT),
                  na.action=na.exclude,
                  data=joint)                  

    return(summary(temp))
    }
    results <- subtype("RACE", covars=...)
    results2 <- subtype("GENDER", covers=...
```

When I did this macro programing in SAS, it was easy.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `lapply(vector_of_variables, subtype)` ?

Comment: That almost worked.  I ran apply(df[,vector], function(x){subtype(main-exposure, x)}.  It ran the model twice, once for each of the two elements I put in the veto, rather than both of them together.

Comment: It's just wonderful that you can do this is SAS. In R `apply` seems completely off-base. Consider looking at `?split` or `?expand.grid`, or `?interaction`, but if you really want a response with a  _coded_ _answer_ then post a real data example.

Comment: I did post a real data example, that code was cut and paste right from my program.